# Is it possible to use Kwallet with Keepass files?

Tags: kde, keepass, kde-plasma-5

Is it possible to use Kwallet, the password manager built in Kde Plasma Desktop, with keepass files? It would be very handy, especially under the portability aspect.

Comment: Check this out [http://thisisnt.com/opening-keepass-securely-and-automatically-in-kde/](http://thisisnt.com/opening-keepass-securely-and-automatically-in-kde/)

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I need. That script makes keepass open at boot, I'd like to know if I can use keepass instead of kwallet. And it is for KDE4, not for the current Plasma 5.

Comment: The subject says the opposite, "Is it possible to use Kwallet **with** Keepass files?" Might want to edit it to "instead of".

Comment: I wrote the comment in a hurry, I actually want to use kwallet with keepass files (not the program) instead of its own format

Comment: From what i can find out that is absolutely no problem.

Comment: And how it is done? I can't find out, that article explains something else. If you know how to do it would you write a full answer?

Comment: If you mean using only KDE wallet with KeePass database, where you will also store passwords into the KeePass database, then i don't think it is possible. You can import the database from KeePass into KDE wallet and then use that as your future password wallet. KeePass also makes KeePassX, which is a linux distribution that uses the same database files cross platform. Sorry if I have misunderstood everything. :-)

Comment: No problem friend, thank you for your effort :)

Answer (score 2):

**Yes this is possible.**

Edit: you where asking to use the Keepass vault for all files. No I dont think this works and its also not really a problem.

But anyways, here is how to automatically unlock KeepassXC with Kwallet (so you dont need to enter the password and it can also be very strong)

1. Open "KWalletManager"
2. If not existent, create a new folder called "Passwords" by clicking on the clear area and then "New"
3. Open that folder, in here you find multiple folders, one is called "Passwords" in your systems language
4. Right click the "Passwords" subfolder and press "new"
5. Name the entry for example "Keepass", click on the entry and "show content", enter your Keepass Password
6. Create an Appstarter for quick-opening your password storage!

You can create an App Desktop Entry like this, open your Terminal and enter:

When using KeepassXC Flatpak:

```
cat > ~/.local/share/applications/keepassxc-unlock.desktop <<EOF
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Keepass-unlock
Comment=Unlock your KeepassXC vault
Exec=kwallet-query -r KeepassXC kdewallet | /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=keepassxc --file-forwarding org.keepassxc.KeePassXC --pw-stdin ~/passwords.kdbx
Icon=emblem-encrypted-unlocked
Type=Application
EOF
```

When using a native package:

```
cat > ~/.local/share/applications/keepassxc-unlock.desktop <<EOF
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Keepass-unlock
Comment=Unlock your KeepassXC vault
Exec=kwallet-query -r KeepassXC kdewallet | keepassxc --pw-stdin ~/passwords.kdbx
Icon=emblem-encrypted-unlocked
Type=Application
EOF
```

(Please use Lemmy or the KDE Discuss for such questions. I just found it shows up very high when searching, so I created an account, was not even possible not even after 20 Recaptchas. So yeah you are welcome.)